# CSS files not getting loaded in my spring MVC application

Tags: css, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, tiles

I have a spring MVC based web application running on Tomcat 7.0. We are also using Tiles framework in the application.

Below is the code for my layout page. In the page I have included some CSS files and javascript files.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Application</title>

        <!-- CSS Files -->
        <link type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css'/>">
        <link type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/styles.css'/>" />

        <!-- Javascript Files -->       
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/common.js'/>"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("input:submit, a, input:button", ".buttonDiv").button();
                $("a", ".buttonDiv").click(function() {
                    return false;
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header">
                    <tiles:putAttribute name="menu"
                        value="/WEB-INF/jsps/common/menu.jsp" />
                </tiles:insertAttribute>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript files are loaded properly but not the CSS files.

Also I have foloowing code in mY spring configuration file.

```
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

I am using IE7 browser. I do not have any other browser to test.

Is there something wrong with the way I am including my CSS files?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try this to add your css file

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line while giving the reference of css, img or script file in jsp

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/xxxx"
    rel="stylesheet">  //xxxx is the resources
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```